# (null) values for Core Data parent entity properties

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have two Core Data Entities: Client and Order, Client is a parent for Orders. I am creating a new Order like this:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];
Order *newOrder = (Order *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];
newOrder.date = [NSDate date];
newOrder.client = self.client;
NSError *error;
if (![context save:&error])
    NSLog(@"Error saving entity: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
```

The client is declared in the controller like this: `@property (nonatomic, retain) Client *client;`

and is set using:

```
- (void)setClient:(Client *)newClient
{
    if (newClient != client) {
        [client release];
        client = [newClient retain];
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I'm trying to access a property of the order's client object, e.g. `order.client.clientID` I'm getting a (null) value, for everyone but the last added order for a given client. It's like the client is saved correctly as parent, but forgotten when I add a new order for the particular client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Client` to `Order` relationship is set one-to-one such that there can only be one Order object in `Client.order` at anyone one time. Whenever you set a new `Order`-->`Client` relationship it bumps the previous Order object out of the relationship.

You have this:

```
Client{
  name:string
  order<-->Order.client
}

Order{
  date:date
  client<-->Client.order
}
```

... when you need:

```
Client{
  name:string
  orders<-->>Order.client
}

Order{
  date:date
  client<<-->Client.orders
}
```

Comment: Indeed, I found out so myself yesterday.. I was using Xcode 4 and didn't see the relationship type because of the new layout..